# how to set headers or authentication in azure logic app http action

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I'm using the basic azure http action step and see a box for authentication and header in the configuration, but no documentation on how to use it or set it.  What's the syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasn't able to use the box, but if you go to code view you can do the following:

1. Add the HTTP module
2. Click Code View
3. Go to Actions and modify headers:

   ```
   "actions": {
   "http": {
       "type": "Http",
       "inputs": {
           "method": "POST",
           "uri": "your URI",
           "headers": {
               "Content-Type": "application/json",
               "Authorization": "Basic *your base64 password*",
               "other header": "other value"
           }
       },
       "conditions": []
   }
   },
   ```